# How can I change my username (not display name)?

Tags: support, users

I know how to change my display name. Can I change my username? (the string I use to log in to the site).

Every question asking about changing username is referring to display name, not to username.

Comment: There is no such thing as a username here. You login with a third-party account or an email/password combination.

Comment: @animuson well, there is the unique user ID per site, but not sure that's what OP here mean.

Comment: "the string I use to log in to the site". Pretty sure it's not the user id, @ShadowWizard.

Answer (score 6):

You use Google to log in. If you want to change or add another credential, you can do so from your profile - click "Edit Profile & Settings" and then "My Logins".